# How can I get the actual value of a variable front an other class (Kotlin / Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, variables, canvas

I have an activity (mainGame.kt and xml) with buttons. When a button is clicked a variable is decreased. From initialized with 2100 to 0.

And I have a CustomView with a Canvas to draw a circle. The layout from the CustomView is in the mainGame.xml.
The CustomView has its own customView.kt. With in the CustomView.kt is an onDraw Method for drawing the circle.

How can I get the actual value from the variable from the mainGame.kt and use in my CustomView to reduce the diameter from the circle?

I have tried to get the variable with: val circleDia = MainGame().circleDiameter.
But I always get the initialized value, not the value at "runtim".

Comment: Use callback or a livedata

Comment: What is the easiest Method? There are differents between them?

Comment: Well, callback is a method/approach with which you can implement the desired feature. Livedata belongs to lifecycle libraries which you have to read and learn before implementing them. I suggest you go with callback now.